# flutter hive putAt key error when delete from list

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

When I delete the employee, an error occurs in the key when I update the employee's data, and I do not understand where the problem is
this error:

> Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 4: 4

this code :

```
 await employeerBox.putAt(
      index,
      employeerModel(
          name: name.text.toString(),
          phoneNumber: int.parse(phoneNumber.text),
          location: location.text.toString(),
          workDate: workDate.text.toString(),
          workType: workType.text.toString(),
          salary: double.parse(salary.text.toString())));
```

index = key

in delete by key no error but in put at give an error
I tried to update the data more than once and close and open the application, but to no avail     [image: screenShoot]

Comment: can you include the UI list widgets implementation ?

Comment: Looks like when  you have 4 items then you delete one the became  3 items then you you want to put in index 4 it will threw  an error because now you have only 3 item, so the solution will be you after deleting update the index or dont use put. Use .add() or .putIfAbsent()  i cant tell exactly because i dot see hour code